# Inline Edit of Field

Tags: apex, visualforce, inlineeditsupport

*I have the following code*

```
<apex:outputField value="{!auth.InviteAcceptedDate__c}">  
     <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" rendered="{!(auth.InviteAcceptedDate__c!=NUll&&auth.InviteSentDate__c!=Null)&&($Profile.Name=='Admin')"/>                      
</apex:outputField>
```

Here I want the InviteAcceptedDate__c to be inline editable only if **1.InviteAcceptedDate__c is not null 2.InviteSentDate__c is not null 3. And the profile of the user is admin**. But the above code doesn't seem to work. I am not sure how to satisfy the conditions. I am fairly new to salesforce, and any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **&&**

```
<apex:outputField value="{!auth.InviteAcceptedDate__c}">  
         <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" 
            rendered="{!(auth.InviteAcceptedDate__c!=NUll)&&
                      (auth.InviteSentDate__c!=Null) &&($Profile.Name=='Admin')}"/>                      
</apex:outputField>
```

Using **AND**

```
<apex:outputField value="{!auth.InviteAcceptedDate__c}">  
     <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" 
                        rendered="{!AND(auth.InviteAcceptedDate__c!=NUll,
                         auth.InviteSentDate__c!=Null,$Profile.Name=='Admin')}"/>                      
</apex:outputField>
```

Comment: really?  the doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_operators.htm says that `&&` is a valid logical AND operator and && works for me